# How give more style on a CSS /Jquery Menu Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menubar

Long time!! :)

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this, it's a jquery menu that I've been using for my website, I would like to know if it's possible to:

[Menu Bar at Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghAkB/6/)

- Put some `vertical line separator on each option of the menu` to separate them 
  without being affected by the hover effect like the text option.
- add to the menu on the corner end on the right a  `small ''social media'' icons (img)`
  each one directing to a specific link 
  just like the text menu. The menu fits the website content (940px width)
  and has extra space but in the fiddle example it doesn't show.
- also important> is there a way to add a `bigger text on the menu` 
  and make each    menu word option bigger by stretching it?  Looks pretty small.Horizontally I mean, vertically it stays the same.

It's important that the underline hover and the rest appears the same just like it's shown in jsfiddle without being affected by these possible changes.

I would deeply appreciate it!!! :)

Comment: Does my answer help you at all?

Comment: yes, absolutely, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few CSS and markup changes you can make to achieve what you'd like

```
#example-one { margin: 0 auto; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 940px; font-family:Arial; }
#example-one li a { color: #bbb; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing:2px; display: block; float: left; padding: 6px 10px 4px 10px; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; border-right: 1px solid white; }
#example-one li:first-child a { border-left:1px solid white; }
```

1. On the first line, you can add your `font-family` to change the font used in your menu.
2. On the second line, I added a `border-right`, and set `letter-spacing:2px`.
3. I added the third line to give a `border-left` to only the first item (so that you get the full appearance of separators).

Also I added this item to your list that you could easily insert a social media icon into:

```
<li style="float:right;"><a style="border:none;" href="#">Social Icon</a></li>
```

You can push it to the right side of the menu using `float:right`.

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghAkB/19/).

Comment: Thank you for helping, Sorry I took too long, I was posting another issue with a news scroller, I'm looking at fiddle, how would I be able to insert the image of the social icon instead of the text?

Comment: Just replace "Social Icon" with an `img` tag.

Comment: I'll try it now on the website and let you know in a sec, thank you, I really appreciate all the help

Comment: I checked it and it works great but now IE gives me an error:Webpage error details Message: Expected '}'
Line: 34
example.js

Comment: also is there a way to make more space between the text?

Comment: It sounds like you are just missing a closing bracket somewhere in your js file, the line number should help you find where. You can use a service like jslint.com to validate your js. For space between text, do you mean between links? Try increasing the left/right padding in the `#example-one li a` CSS element.

Comment: Found the error! Thank you so much for you time and help, deeply appreciate it :) A relief, now the menu has more character. I'm sorry if I'm intruding with one more question if you can please check it out only if you can, the thing is that I don't know what do, until the news scroller is sorted I'm kinda stuck with the entire website, the link of the question is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914731/scrolling-news-ticker-jquery

Comment: Sorry for disturbing again but is there a way to remove the first line before "home " and last line at the end of "contact"? keeping the rest of the lines there.

Comment: don't forget to mark as answer if this helped you, if I get a chance I'll try to look at the other. To remove the lines you'll just have to adjust the border styling.